# IOS - MBProgressHUD set Custom Background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

Bydefault MBProgressHUD came with black background color. i know how to change this color to blue or green or etc. But Is it possible to set **custom Background image** in Background on MBProgressHUD?

[image: I want to set custom my application's suitable background image in place of Black color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to set image

```
hudProgress.color =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourBackground.png"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the header file you see state for the HUD and a way to set the custom view.

```
/**
* The UIView (e.g., a UIImageView) to be shown when the HUD is in MBProgressHUDModeCustomView.
* For best results use a 37 by 37 pixel view (so the bounds match the built in indicator bounds). 
*/
@property (MB_STRONG) UIView *customView;
```

So you need to create a custom UIView and pass that to the HUD you create before calling .show